# How can we use Figma.createPage method to make Figma page. I want to create web html into Figma Design using Figma plugin API

Tags: figma, figma-api, figma-plugin

I am new in figma Plugin API. I want to import web url into Figma design page with Custom figma plugin development API.

In the Figma documentation, they provide Figma.createPage but dont has any explanations how can we use it

Thanks

I am expecting how can we create any figma page using figma plugin API.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.